# JCL querying form JIRA serivce plugin

Tags: jira-plugin

I have an JIRA service which runs periodically. I need to look for an certain issues. For this I am using the search service. Because service is running without user context I have no user so I am passing `null` into search method.

I am able to search the `Story` type issues from  JIRA UI, so they seem to be indexed. But in the plugin the result is always 0 hits.

Not sure if the problem is in `null` user or something else. This should be a common scenario, but I was not able to find an example.

```
public class IssueService extends com.atlassian.jira.service.AbstractService {

    @ComponentImport
    @Inject
    private SearchService searchService;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JqlClauseBuilder jqlClauseBuilder = JqlQueryBuilder.newClauseBuilder();
        com.atlassian.query.Query query = jqlClauseBuilder.issueType("Story").buildQuery();
        PagerFilter pagerFilter = PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter();
        com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchResults searchResults = null;
        try {
            searchResults = searchService.search(null, query, pagerFilter);
        } catch (SearchException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        List<Issue> issueList = searchResults.getIssues();
    }

    //rest method omitted
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was to use the following method:

```
SearchResults searchResults = 
searchService.searchOverrideSecurity(null, query, pagerFilter);
```